# Barcodes too wide in a GoDEX printer with CUPS in Linux

Tags: drivers, pdf, cups, printer, ghostscript

I have a **GoDEX RT700i** printer (203 DPI) and I want to print barcodes in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)
The barcodes I have are in PDF format. There is a 8 digit number below the barcode.

In Windows, there is no problem with GoDEX drivers. The barcodes and the number are printed perfectly.

In Linux, when I print the barcode, the digits of the number are okay, same as Windows, and the height of the bars is okay too, but the width of every bar is bigger than the displayed in the pdf.

How can I fix this?

[Here a photo of the printed barcodes](http://www.monkers.net/uploads/barcodes.jpg)
The left one has printed in Linux and the right one has printed in Windows.

## There is some additional information:

For Linux I have compiled and installed the GoDEX driver for **CUPS** and then I have added the printer via AppSocket/HP JetDirect with the IP and Port (9100).

Then, I select the PPD file godex-rt-700i.ppd

These two lines are in the ppd file. Maybe they are related with the problem:

```
 TTRasterizer: Type42
 *cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-raster 50 rastertoezpl"
```

When I send the print order, I realized that there are 3 filters for the job:

```
pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
rastertoezpl (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/GODEX-RT700i, cost 50)
```

In the *rastertoezpl.c* file I saw that there is a function (**GDXCompress**) that compress the output lines for Godex printer. 
I thought that maybe the compression affects somehow to the barcode and I tried to deactivate that function (**CompBuffer = NULL**) and recompile the driver, but that didn't fix anything.

**Versions:**

```
Ghostscript = GPL Ghostscript 9.18 Artifex Software
cups = 2.1.3-4
pdftopdf = cups-filters 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1
```

Any suggestions to fix that problem with the width of the bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDF contains a bitmap/image representation of the bar code that is not 203 PPI/DPI then Ghostscript will need to subsample the image leading to the kind of output issues you are seeing. Please check these posts:
https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/4820.
https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_Your_Own_Filters_to_Print_with_CUPS